# How can I display my custom posts type in a monthly calendar view?

Tags: custom-post-types, calendar

I am looking for a way to display my Custom Post Type posts in a full-page monthly calendar type display (like what you see in Google calendar). Ideally, the calendar would be dynamic in which user could click from month to month. And I would want the actual post titles to be displayed and linked in the squares.

I know there are a multitude of "event calendar" plugins, but that is not what I am looking for. I want to control the content type that is displayed. There is also the built-in Calendar widget but that seems way too basic and I can't see a way of filtering by content type.

This is the sort of thing that I could do very easily in Drupal with the views calendar module, but I am at a loss at how to achieve this display in Wordpress.

I am hoping there is a plugin that can accomplish this, but I am open to coded solutions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (and requests for plugin recommendations) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you read my question you would see that I also would like a way to do this in code or via some sort of built-in Wordpress function.